# A bankSystem program in PHP

Tags: php, class

I am trying to solve this problem, but can not get the idea of how this can be done. I don't have much that experience in PHP. Kindly help me with that

---

Create a class **BankSyS** which hold information regarding customer.

- **customerAcct**
- **customeName**
- **accouTtype  (saving / current)**
- **accountAge**
- **Balance**

There will two types of account saving and current. In saving account there will 5% of interest added of the balance amount to the balance of that customer per year (on the basis of account age). While in current account there will be no interest. 
There should be the following member functions 
**getBalance():** return the current customer account balance 
**Deposit ():** which take a parameter amount and add it to the balance of the that customer. Amount must be greater than 0 and not negative. 
**setCustomerInfo():** Input Customer Information. 
**getCustomerInfo():** show Customer Information in Tabular Form. 
**Withdraw():** withdraw member function will withdraw the amount from the customer account but withdraw amount must not be greater than the current balance. 
Customer balance should be initialized at the time of customer account creation/opening. The account opening limit is $5000 Minimum 
To the run the programming create five customers, and create menu 
1. Add Customer Information 
2. Deposit Amount 
3. Withdraw Amount. 
4. Display Customer Information. 
5. Check Customer Balance

**That's what I tried**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
class BankSys {
  public $customerAcct;
  public $customerName;
  public $accountType;
  public $accountAge;
  public $balance;

  function set_Name($customerName) {
    $this->name = $customerName;
  }

  function get_Name() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  function setBalance($balance) {
    $this->balance = $balance;
  }
  function getBalance() {
    return $this->balance;
  }
}

$user1 = new BankSys();
$user1->set_Name('John');
$user1->setBalance(5000);
echo "Balance: " . $user1->getBalance();
echo "Name: " . $user1->get_Name();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? and what is the problem that you want us to help you to solve?

Comment: @catcon I added my code above

Comment: @IhtishamKhan where is the question?

Comment: @Mointy I added a horizontal line above the question. Question is starting below that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change everything with `public` to `private`.

```
private $customerAcct;
private $customerName;
private $accountType;
private $accountAge;
private $balance;
```

Then you need a constructor with a set name function like this:

```
function __construct($name, $balance) 
    $this->set_name($name);
    $this->accountAge = 0;
    $this->accountType = 2;
    $this->customerAcct = something;

    if(empty($balance)){
        $this->balance = 5000; //Standard amount
    } else {
        //Check if $balance is an int
        $this->balance = $balance; // If you type something in 
    }
    
}

function set_name($newName) {
    //Check if that name is possible or not, then set name
    $this->name = $newName;
}
```

There shouldn't be function to set the balance. Balance should only change when withdraw or deposit method is called.

```
function getBalance() {
    return $this->balance;
}

function withdraw($amount) {
    $this->balance = $this->getBalance() - $amount;
}

function deposit($amount) {
    if($amout <= 0){
        return;
    }

    $this->balance = $this->getBalance() + $amount;
}
```

You wouldn't do that `getCustomerInfo()`. You would create a table outside the class and then use the get methods to get info

Usage:

```
$user1 = new BankSys('John', 7000); 
$user1->withdraw(300); //Withdraw 300
$user1->deposit(300); //Deposit 300
```

Create a html table and do `<?php echo $user1->getName(); ?>` in a cell to display data.

Comment: How I show you my edited code now?

Comment: @IhtishamKhan what exactly is missing that you need?

Comment: 1) Want to use that data in to show in a table. 2) Want to use withdraw and deposit function

Comment: already used <?php echo $user1->getName(); ?>. Getting an error with that

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method BankSys::set_name() in C:\xampp\htdocs ..............

Comment: Look again at my answer, the second code box there is the function that you copy in your class.